# How to play video player one after another in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

i want to play video in ios one after another..I have two video files .m3u8 format. if video one completed then video two start automatically.. after video two complete then again video one should played automatically. and again video two should start automatically. how can i do this thing….I am using Mediaplayer framework. plz give me any idea…..Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

 NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"buyTutorial" ofType:@“m3u8”];

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;

[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];

[moviePlayerController play];

[self setController:moviePlayerController];

}
```

Comment: You have some solid help in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this notification:

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

And then look for this constant `PlaybackEnded`:

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieFinishReason

Then just start the next movie in your playback queue.

---

Here's some examples on how to register to the notification:

[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification being called again in iPhone 4.3 simulator when setting contentURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289401/mpmovieplayerplaybackdidfinishnotification-being-called-again-in-iphone-4-3-simu)